# Passing list to view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my action method from controller.

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
        private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();

        // GET: /Movies/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View( db.Movies.ToList() );
        }
}
```

As it can be seen a `List` is being passed to `View` that is why I am expecting to work with it as `List`in `view` but in `View` it works as `IEnumerable`

Following is the first line from `View`

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCWebApplication2.Models.Movie>
```

Why passed value that was `List` behaves as `IEnumerable`?
Is `IEnumerable` super class of `List`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>` implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

It is typically a best practice to try to work with interfaces where possible to keep your code decoupled, so that's why the `View` was scaffolded like that. In this instance, you could pass any other `Movie` collection that implements `IEnumerable<T>` to your `View`, and your `View` would happily render without issue.

So, imagine you have another `Action` in some other `Controller` like:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Queue<Movie> movies = new Queue<Movie>();
        movies.Enqueue(db.Movies.Single(m => m.Title == "Flash Gordon"));
        movies.Enqueue(db.Movies.Single(m => m.Title == "Star Wars"));
        return View( "Movie/Index", movies );
    }
```

Because `Queue<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, `movies` will get rendered by the same `View` without having to make any changes to it. If your `View` was typed to `List<Movies>`, you would need to create a whole separate `View` to accommodate your `Queue<Movies>` model!

Answer (score 3):

As Chris mentioned, `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so that is why it is valid for the View's model to be:

```
 @model IEnumerable<MVCWebApplication2.Models.Movie>
```

Since you said you want to use it as a `List`, the List **also** implements `IList<T>` which should provide you with the functionality you were expecting to have in your view.

You can make use of the List methods like so:

```
@model IList<MVCWebApplication2.Models.Movie>
<div>
    First movie: @Model.First().Name
</div>

@Model.Count Action Movies:
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.Type = "ActionMovie"))
    {
        <li>@item.Name - @item.Description</li>
    }
</ul>
```